# Send AWS X-Ray traces and segments to the AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-xray

I looking for a solution to send the logs from **AWS-Xray** to **AWS CloudWatch** to help me doing an aggregation and metrics.

I was checking if we can do this directly using **AWS X-Ray** daemon, it seems there is no way to do this form the X-Ray daemon.

I can see that the only solution to do so using Get the trace summary from Xray using **AWS XRAY SDK API** and share to other streams like CloudWatch.

Is there a solution to conduct this using a config in  **AWS X-Ray daemon** to send the logs directly to CloudWatch log group?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately xray daemon only support X-Ray endpoint by `PutTraceSegments` API, it cannot emit metrics or logs to CloudWatch.
Alternatively, you can choose ADOT collector which is a all-in-one agent.
https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/collector